# How to make Time.to_s(:db) with microseconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I want to compare times in microsecond accuracy, so I created new `Time::DATA_FORMATS` like this.

```
 Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db_usec] = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N'
```

But with this format the time is formated with local time zone.
I have to change the time in `UTC` first.

```
Post.created_at.utc.to_s(:db_usec)
```

How can I write a `DATE_FORMATS` like `:db` that formats the time in `UTC`?

Comment: are you aware about `strftime` method of ruby ?

Comment: yes, but I couldn't find how to make it in UTC.

Comment: The DateTime by default store in `UTC`  , did you used different time zone in your app.rb ?

Comment: `app.rb` is used in `sinatra`, right? I'm configure my rails app in different time zone. But `Time.to_s(:db)` returns the string in UTC time anyway.

Comment: Are you asking about `DATE_FORMATS`, or about `DATA_FORMATS`?

Comment: did you create time_formats.rb initializers ?

Comment: just try to add format `%Y-%m-%d` and check whether db_usec giving this format in return ? it is used for only formatting of date and time.

Comment: @sawa sorry, misspelled. `DATE_FROMATS`.

Comment: @Vishal it return as it expected and `to_s(:db_usec)` returns in local timezone with micro seconds.

Comment: @ironsand What is the difference between `DATE_FORMATS`, `DATA_FORMATS`, and `DATE_FROMATS`?

Comment: All I mean was `DATE_FORMATS`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change it by referring to the [Rails api link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s).

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db_usec] = ->(time) { time.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N') }
```

Comment: I see, I can use lambda with the method. Thanks.